# Iboutlets have nil value on present call

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, iboutlet

```swift
@objc func handleGoToSearch() {
//        present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchDisplayController()), animated: true, completion: nil)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchSegue", sender: nil)
    }
```

I was using the present call to SearchViewController but the ib outlets on where nil, I have a feeling it has something to do with passing a new instance, and the outlets are not loading in time. (What I read somewhere else). when I use perform segue not errors.

I would like to know exactly what's happening. I also thought that maybe present() doesn't work with storyboard, or I'm passing in the wrong value type.

Comment: `present` does work with storyboards. make sure that the ViewController's class (in storyboard) is set to the swift class correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outlets are nil because you are not creating the viewcontroller from the Swift class only, not from the storyboard. To create the viewcontroller from the storyboard, do this:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Name of the storyboard").instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier of the viewcontroller")
```

You should fill in the name of the storyboard (usually `Main`) and give the viewcontroller an identifier in the storyboard, and use that identifier in the code.